# Is the following inequality proof correct?

Tags: inequality

Consider the following inequality transformations:

$ |x + y|^2 = (x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \geq x^2 - 2|x| |y| + y^2 = |x|^2 - 2 |x| |y| + |y|^2 = (|x|-|y|)^2 = | |x| - |y| |^2  \Longleftrightarrow |x + y|^2 \geq | |x| - |y| |^2 \Longleftrightarrow  |x + y| \geq | |x| - |y| |$

Does this seem correct?

**Edit:** I made use of facts proven earlier in my course that aren't mentioned in the proof above, so my question should have rather been whether the transformations I did are correct since for being a rigorous proof I would obviously have to mention the Corollaries I made use of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all looks correct.

It's worth noting, however, that you'll need to justify that $$xy\geq-|x||y|$$ and that $$|x+y|^2\geq \bigl||x|-|y|\bigr|^2\Longrightarrow |x+y|\geq \bigl||x|-|y|\bigr|.$$ The former is almost trivial, and I leave it to you, but the latter might take a bit of work. Personally, I'd proceed by supposing we have some $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $|a|^2\ge|b|^2.$ Clearly, if $a=0$ and $b=0,$ then we have $|a|\ge|b|,$ and if not, then each of the following implies the next: $$|a|^2\ge|b|^2\\|a|^2-|b|^2\ge0\\\bigl(|a|+|b|\bigr)\bigl(|a|-|b|\bigr)\ge0\\|a|-|b|\ge0\\|a|\geq|b|.$$ Do you see how to justify each step?

Comment: Related on Meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20098/42969